# Subscribe Gate Implementation | Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app for which user grant me permission to access `user_subscriptions` to make my app able to access `https://graph.facebook.com/me/subscribedto?access_token=#`

It let me access all the persons app user is subscribed to.

I use this data let my app know that the user is subscribed to a particular person and let him/her access the site furter, I call this process a `Subscribe Gate`.

But I'm running into a problem now, that suppose a user is subscribed to about 1K or even 5-10K, then in such case think about the amount of data will be transferred and the load on the php server, facebook will consider my app spam and might block me

I want to know is there a way through which I could `search` for the person whom user is subscribed to instead of asking for all the persons user is subscribed to and check manually by php script

Comment: Hello....posting a new question with just a link to an earlier one is not the way to get attention for your posts. Also, be patient, your question has only been on the site for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know if a particular person is subscribed to the user of the app. Supposing the person in question's user id is XXXXXXXX, do...

via **Graph**:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select subscriber_id from subscription where subscribed_id = me()  and subscriber_id='XXXXXXXX'
```

or via **FQL**:

```
select subscriber_id from subscription where subscribed_id = me()  and subscriber_id='XXXXXXXX'
```

-

**Note**: while in theory the above solutions should work equally well, when I tested the *Graph*-based solution with the Facebook Graph explorer, the query processed for an unusually long time. FQL worked fine.

**Update**: To find out if the user of the app is subscribed to a particular person:

```
select subscriber_id from subscription where subscribed_id = 'XXXXXXXXX' and subscriber_id = me()
```

Comment: both the method gave empty `data` array even if the user is subscribed

Comment: also will it detect the user subscription if the user is friend of the subscribed?

Comment: In my test data was empty only if person was *not* subscribed to the app user. Did you chose the proper permissions first? It will detect non-friends who are subscribed.

Comment: Got it! Actually the query must be 

`select subscriber_id from subscription where subscribed_id = 'XXXX_USER_ID_XXXX' and subscriber_id = me()`

Comment: You're too close but this `FQL query` fail when the person to subscribe is a friend of the person who's subscribing

Comment: "If I understand correctly, you want to know if a particular person is subscribed to the user of the app." you did not correct me, actually you were looking for *if the user of the app is subscribed to a particular person*

Comment: I ended up using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/subscribedto/USER_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` , and if give empty `data` means the person is not subscribed to USER_ID then I check if the USER_ID is friend of the subscriber or not by `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/USER_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=id` if still it give empty array that means the person is really not subscribed